# How to convert Matlab's fisheye calibration results into OpenCV format?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am using Matlab's Camera Calibrator to calibrate a bunch of images from a fisheye camera.

How can I translate the results into OpenCV format?

Results in Matlab:

[image]

Format I would like to convert them to:

[image]
[image]

I looked into and found out that Scaramuzza's model is the one that the Matlab fisheye calibration uses, but I don't see clearly anywhere what exactly each value stands for, or the order.

Edit: The cameraIntrinsicsToOpenCV function provided by Matlab does not work with fisheye models, it is only for pinhole/default camera model, hence the question!

Comment: Distortion center is cx and cy but take care about x/y image axis differences in opencv and matlab. If image width is 320 then cx is more likely the 158.1319.

Comment: those "mapping coefficients"... the first one looks outrageous, so it's probably *not* `k1` from the opencv model... it *might* be the **focal length**. -- even then, matlab's distortion coefficients might be normalized by focal length, or they might not. _check_ that the resulting picture looks okay, by calibrating on a seriously distorted lens, so you can tell if the math is... fishy

Answer (score 2):

From version R2021b, Matlab has introduced the `cameraIntrinsicsToOpenCV` function which does exactly that. Read more [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraintrinsicstoopencv.html)

They also made it bijective with its twin function `cameraIntrinsicsFromOpenCV`.

**Edit:**
For fisheye cameras, use `undistortFisheyeImage` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/undistortfisheyeimage.html) to get the `cameraIntrinsics` which will contain all the data for opencv: FocalLength [fx fy] , PrincipalPoint [cx, cy], RadialDistortion [k1 k2 k3] and TangentialDistortion [p1 p2].

```
[UndistortedImage,camIntrinsics] = undistortFisheyeImage(Image,intrinsics);
```

Comment: The fisheye model in matlab does not support this

Comment: Can you specify the returned error ?

Comment: Error using cameraIntrinsicsToOpenCV
Expected intrinsics to be one of these types:
cameraIntrinsics, cameraParameters
Instead its type was fisheyeParameters.

Comment: Added edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works but returns [0,0,0,0,0] for the distortion values

Comment: You can plot to check if the `UndistortedImage` is really undistorted. If that's the case then the returned camIntrinsics is good and contains all the data you need for opencv: FocalLength [fx fy] , PrincipalPoint [cx, cy], RadialDistortion [k1 k2 k3] and TangentialDistortion [p1 p2]. From this standpoint, You can basically omit using `cameraIntrinsicsToOpenCV`.